# Find to mime the LeftJoin in CakePhp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have 3 models:

1. User
2. Like
3. Post

Like has 2 foreign key set using CakePHP convention on `user_id` and `post_id` (that are the `id` column of the other 2 models).

I want to run a find that mime the `LEFT JOIN` in sql on `Post` with a condition on the foreign key.

In detail i want:

- 1: all the posts.
- 1a: if the post have a like from the user XXX I want it included in the result
- 1b: else the post doesn't have a ->Like attribute.

So, if i do this:

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('all');
```

in $posts i have all the posts, and for each posts all the likes.

Reading the book, I feel like i should write something like:

```
$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'likes',
        'alias' => 'Likes',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Post.id = Likes.post_id',
            'Likes.user_id = 536f6a29-babc-4724-a74d-2ce100000000'
        )
      )
    ); 


    $posts = $this->Post->find('all', $options);
```

But this doesn't work.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Show us what you have tried already and what are the problems you encounter.

Comment: Check the joins and `Containable` behavior on the books. They can help you: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html; http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you need put in your models

```
class User extends AppModel
{ 
    public $useTable = 'users';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $hasMany = array(
    'Post',
    'Like'
    );
}

class Post extends AppModel
{ 
    public $useTable = 'posts';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $belongsTo = array('User');
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Like'
    );
}
class Like extends AppModel
{ 
    public $useTable = 'likes';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $belongsTo = array('Post','User');
}
```

and in you controller

```
$this->loadModel("User");
$query = $this->User->find('all', array(
         'joins' => array(
              array(
                'table' => 'posts',
                'alias' => 'Post',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                'User.id = Post.user_id'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'likes',
                'alias' => 'Like',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                'User.id = Like.user_id'
                )
            )
        ),
            'conditions' => array(
            'Post.id = Likes.post_id',
            'Likes.user_id = 536f6a29-babc-4724-a74d-2ce100000000'
        ),
            'order' => array(
            'Post.id' => 'ASC'
        ),
            'fields' => array('Post.*','User.id'),

            'recursive' => -1
        ));
```

Comment: Is the declaration in the model of the id and useTable mandatory, or can i omit if i use the right naming convention?

Comment: if you use the conventions you can omit